# How to transfer data from table to table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to transfer data from one table to another and also i want add an additional column in second table.

```
INSERT INTO invoiceitem(invoiceno, barcode, itemname, quantity, unitprice, subamount)
VALUES
    ('$Succ2', SELECT barcode, resultname, quantity, resultprice, subamount)
FROM test;
```

Comment: second table i have additional column invoiceno. then i want to add $succ2 variable value to that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert values from one table to another, need not use VALUES in insert query. pls refer [INSERT TABLE TO ANOTHER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO invoiceitem (invoiceno, barcode, itemname, quantity, unitprice, subamount)
SELECT '$Succ2' barcode, resultname, quantity, resultprice, subamount
FROM test;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert using the result set of a query, the syntax is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, i.e. we do not use `VALUES` in this case.  It is possible to add a literal value to a `SELECT` statement, e.g. try this:

```
INSERT INTO invoiceitem (invoiceno, barcode, itemname, quantity, unitprice, subamount)
SELECT '$Succ2', barcode, resultname, quantity, resultprice, subamount
FROM test;
```

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO invoiceitem(invoiceno,barcode,itemname,quantity,unitprice,subamount)
SELECT '$Succ2' ,barcode,resultname,quantity,resultprice,subamount FROM test;
```